# image is not displayed correctly while loading cell with entries in searchbar iOS swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

Here I am trying to display the filtered data results when the searching starts.The searching of the name works but I don't understand how to take the image with the search to display.I think the error is in filter content for search I'm new to iOS and any help will be appreciated

```
   import UIKit
    import Foundation
    import SDWebImage

    class TableViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating {
        //var sections = ["recent","old"]
        var TableData:Array<String> = Array <String>()
        //var TableDataRecent:Array<String> = Array <String>()
        var TableImage:Array<String> = Array <String>()
        var appoid:Array<String> = Array <String>()


        var filteredArray:[String]=[]
        var filteredImage:[String]=[]
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            getData()
            self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cells")
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation=false
            definesPresentationContext=true
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
        //
        //    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        //
        //        return sections[section]
        //
        //    }
        //
        //    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        //        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        //
        //        return sections.count
        //
        //    }



        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if searchController.isActive && !searchController.searchBar.isEqual("") {
                return self.filteredArray.count
            }
            else{
                return TableData.count
            }
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            //here cells is the identifier name of prototype cell

            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cells", for: indexPath)

            if searchController.isActive && !searchController.searchBar.isEqual(""){
                cell.textLabel?.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
                //cell.imageView?.image = filteredImage[indexPath.row]
    //            print("filteredimage")
    //            print(filteredImage)
    //            print(indexPath.row)
                cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: TableImage[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "PA"))
                print(TableData[indexPath.row])

                print(appoid[indexPath.row])
            }
            else{
                cell.textLabel?.text = self.TableData[indexPath.row]
                //cell.imageView?.image = self.TableImage[indexPath.row]
                cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: TableImage[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "PA"))
            //cell.= appoid[indexPath.row]

            }


        return cell
    }





    func filterContentForSearch(searchString:String){
        self.filteredArray=self.TableData.filter(){nil != $0.range(of:searchString)}
     self.filteredImage=self.TableImage.filter(){nil != $0.range(of:searchString)}

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filterContentForSearch(searchString: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }




    func getData() {


        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "*********")!)
        //request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //let postString = "date="+x
        //request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        //print(request.httpBody)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            do{

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]

                if let stations = json["result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for station in stations {
                        let name = station["patient_name"] as! String
                        //self.login = login_value
                        let profile_pic = station["image"] as! String
                        let status = station["status"] as! String

                        let appo_id = station["id"] as! String
                    //    let appo_id = station["appointment_id"] as! String
                        //let status = station["status"] as! String
                        //let appo_time = station["appointment_time"] as! String
                        //let appo_duration = station["time_duration"] as! String
                        //let reason = station["reason"] as! String
                        print(name,status)

                        self.TableData.append(name)
                        self.TableImage.append(profile_pic)
                        self.appoid.append(appo_id)

                    }







                    print(self.TableData)
                    print(self.TableImage)
                    //print(self.items)
                    //self.do_table_refresh();
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }

            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }



        }
        task.resume()



    }






}
```

Comment: did you got urls in filteredImage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont keep separate array for image, data and appoid. Create struct object and do the search on the struct object.
Try this,

```
import UIKit
   import Foundation
   import SDWebImage

   struct TableObject {
    var name: String = ""
    var image: String = ""
    var appoId: String = ""
   }

   class TableViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating {
    //var sections = ["recent","old"]
    var tableDataSource: [TableObject] = []

    var filteredArray: [TableObject] = []
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getData()
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cells")
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation=false
        definesPresentationContext=true
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //
    //    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    //
    //        return sections[section]
    //
    //    }
    //
    //    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    //
    //        return sections.count
    //
    //    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchController.isActive && !searchController.searchBar.isEqual("") {
            return self.filteredArray.count
        }
        else{
            return tableDataSource.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //here cells is the identifier name of prototype cell

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cells", for: indexPath)

        if searchController.isActive && !searchController.searchBar.isEqual(""){
            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredArray[indexPath.row].name
            //cell.imageView?.image = filteredImage[indexPath.row]
            //            print("filteredimage")
            //            print(filteredImage)
            //            print(indexPath.row)
            cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: filteredArray[indexPath.row].image), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "PA"))
        }
        else{
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.TableData[indexPath.row]
            //cell.imageView?.image = self.TableImage[indexPath.row]
            cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: tableDataSource[indexPath.row].image), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "PA"))
            //cell.= appoid[indexPath.row]

        }


        return cell
    }





    func filterContentForSearch(searchString:String){
        self.filteredArray=self.tableDataSource.filter(){nil != $0.name.range(of:searchString)}

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filterContentForSearch(searchString: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }




    func getData() {


        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "*********")!)
        //request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //let postString = "date="+x
        //request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        //print(request.httpBody)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            do{

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]

                if let stations = json["result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for station in stations {
                        let name = station["patient_name"] as! String
                        //self.login = login_value
                        let profile_pic = station["image"] as! String
                        let status = station["status"] as! String

                        let appo_id = station["id"] as! String
                        //    let appo_id = station["appointment_id"] as! String
                        //let status = station["status"] as! String
                        //let appo_time = station["appointment_time"] as! String
                        //let appo_duration = station["time_duration"] as! String
                        //let reason = station["reason"] as! String
                        print(name,status)
                        let tableData = TableObject(name: name, image: profile_pic, appoId: appo_id)
                        self.tableDataSource.append(tableData)

                    }
                    //print(self.items)
                    //self.do_table_refresh();
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }

            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these

Dont make separate array :

```
 let arrData = [Any]() // these combined array
```

**Change while get data**

```
if let stations = json["result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        for station in stations {
                            arrData.append(station)
                        }
```

**Changes on TableViewDatasource**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if searchController.isActive && !searchController.searchBar.isEqual("") {
                return self.filteredArray.count
            }
            else{
                return arrData.count
            }
        }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //here cells is the identifier name of prototype cell

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cells", for: indexPath)

               if searchController.isActive && !searchController.searchBar.isEqual(""){
                     let dictObjects = filteredArray[indexPath.row] as [String: AnyObject]
                  cell.textLabel?.text = dictObjects["name"]
              cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:  dictObjects["image"]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "PA"))
        }
        else{
        let dictObjects = arrData[indexPath.row] as [String: AnyObject]

            cell.textLabel?.text = dictObjects["name"]
            cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:  dictObjects["image"]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "PA"))
        //cell.= appoid[indexPath.row]

        }

    return cell
}
```

**Filter using this**

```
let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name like %@","yourstring");
filteredArray = arrData.filter { namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0) };
print("names = ,\(filteredArray)");
```